# Redirecting Error in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

Following are methods in UserController

```
     public function callSignupForm($email) {

            return View::make('Signup')->with('email', $email);

    }

    public function SignuptoDatabase() {

        $input = Input::all();

        $email = Input::get('emailText');


        $name = Input::get('nameText');
        $username = Input::get('usernameText');
        $password = Input::get('pwd');
        $confirmpassword = Input::get('cpwd');
        $Gender = Input::get('Gender');

        $rules = array(
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
            'confirmpassword' => 'same:password',
            'Gender' => 'required|in:Male,Female'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if ($validator->passes()) {

            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $name;
            $user->username = $username;
            $user->password = password;
            $user->email = email;
            $user->save();
        }
return Redirect::action('UserController@callSignupForm')->withErrors($validator)->with('email', $email);
    }
```

Signup.blade.php

```
     {{Form::open(array('url'=>'signuptoDatabase'))}}
             @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

                            <p class="errorMessage">{{ $error }}</p>

                            @endforeach
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailText" value='{{$email}}'/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameText">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameText">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ConfirmPassword</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpwd" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gender</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="Gender" name="Male" checked="true">Male</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="Gender" name="Female">Female</label>
            </div>

               </div>  
            <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="submit" Id="registersubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" >Submit</button>
            </div>
</div>            
        {{Form::close()}}
```

After calling , SignuptoDatabase function in UserController. If there any errors. I'm trying to redirect to same page with errors and Input.

I tried

```
return Redirect::action('UserController@callSignupForm')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);

Redirect::back()
```

and also through routing, my route looks as

```
Route::post('callsignupform','UserController@callSignupForm');
```

nothing works..Can any one suggest me solution...

Comment: see that you try to call class method in form. Routes are for link geration, and method pointing, so, as you define name of 'casssignupform', it should be in your form. in my opinion it is better to use named routes. Add 'as' => 'signuptoDatabase' to route params, and change url to action in form. Should work that way

Answer (score 0):

Use return statement like this

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator->messages())->withInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use return stament similarly like this

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('message','Woops! There were some problems with your input.');
```

And add following code to your view file to display your error

```
<?php echo Session::get("message");?>
```